# Lower bound on $tr(A^{-1})$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric, positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix with $n \geq 2$. Does the following inequality then hold?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} > \frac{1}{\lambda_\min},
$$
where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\lambda_\min := \min_{i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}} \left( \lambda_i \right)$.

---

**Thoughts so far**:

A simpler inequality that clearly holds is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \geq \frac{n}{\lambda_\max},
$$
but that doesn't seem useful in this situation.

Also, I realize that the left hand size is $\text{trace}(A^{-1})$, not sure what to do with this.

---

**Background:**

An inequality in some lecture notes that I'm reading *seems* to implicitly hinge on this claim. Specifically, the following is stated as a portion of a longer discourse:
$$
\sigma^2 \sum_{i = 1}^p \frac{1}{\lambda_i} > \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda_\min},
$$
where $(X^T X)$ is a positive definite matrix, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

Comment: For positive matrix, $\lambda_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be obvious $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} > \frac{1}{\lambda_\min}$$

Because the eigenvalues are positive and one of the eigenvalues, say $\lambda_j$ is the minimum eigenvalue. Thus    $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} = \frac{1}{\lambda_\min} + \sum _{i\ne j} \frac{1}{\lambda_i}  > \frac{1} {\lambda_\min}$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Since the eigenvalues are positive, all the terms in the sum are positive. Therefore, the sum is larger than **any** of its terms.